# CSS Class around row not working

Tags: html, css

I want to loop replies. In doing so, I want each reply to look nice with its own background and spacing from each other one. In doing so, I placed a div tag around the reply itself, however, it doesn't seem to be working. I tested with a border, and it seems like the borders are staying at the very top of the container instead of putting themselves around the reply. Here's some code

```
echo "<table>";
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
   $revuserid = $query3['userid'];
   $review = $query3['review'];
   $revtime = $query3['time'];
   $revuser = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select username, id from users where id='{$revuserid}'"));
       $revusername = $revuser['username'];

    echo "<div class=reviews><tr><td><a href=viewuser.php?pid=$revuserid>$revusername</td></tr><tr><td>$review</td></tr><tr><td>Date: $revtime</td></tr></div>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo $centerPages;
```

In HTML, all this is:

```
<table>
    <div class=reviews><tr><td><a href=viewuser.php?pid=$revuserid>$revusername</td></tr><tr><td>$review</td></tr><tr><td>Date: $revtime</td></tr></div>
</table>
```

notice the class div in the loop.

In css, I have for testing the class.

```
.reviews {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put your <tr> elements inside a <div> element.
That is not acceptable to HTML.
Do one of the following:

1. add the class to your <tr> elements (ex.  `<tr class="reviews">`)
2. add the class to your <td> elements (ex.  `<td class="reviews">`)
3. put the <div> element inside the <td>.
4. something I haven't thought about.

Comment: +1 for being ridiculously fast..! And, also, for providing a full answer that was better than my first draft. =)

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Did you mean "Red, US geological survey, bagel puppy"?